# AWS Cloudformation template configuration is not valid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-cloudformation

[image]
I am trying to use template configuration with aws cloudformation (using aws codepipeline). The idea is to use different configuration file for same SAM template for different stack or change set (test or prod stack). I did all the configuration like

```
 Template* build-output::ciSamTemplate.yml
 Template configuration build-output::ciDevTagConfig.json
```

But I am getting error "Template configuration is not valid". My template configuration file has below minimal configuration.

```
{
  "Parameters" : {
    "env" : "dev",
    "apiStage" : "tagDev"
  },
  "StackPolicy" : {
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "NotAction" : "Update:Delete",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Resource" : "*"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I am not sure what is causing this template configuration file to fail? I don't know how can i debug this ?

Comment: Got the same problem, checked the cloudwatch logs to see if there was anything there, also made sure to give plenty of permissions to cloudformation for creating the resources. But "the computer says no"...

Answer (score 4):

I had this error because the codepipeline configuration file uses a different format to the standard cloudformation parameters file. See this gist -> https://gist.github.com/g-a-d/4bc7f716bc57e42b64e1ef450be9bae8

Comment: You can also find the format here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/continuous-delivery-codepipeline-cfn-artifacts.html#w2ab1c21c15c15

Answer (score 2):

I am a bit late, but maybe it helps someone in the future.

I had the same issue and had to change my Template Configuration file's encoding from **UTF-8 BOM** to just normal **UTF-8** and that did the trick for me.

Answer (score 2):

This error message can appear when your JSON for the *parameter file* is invalid.

JSON follows strict syntax rules.

For example if you are missing a comma or a curly bracket, then your JSON will be invalid.

If you are passing CloudFormation a file of parameters in JSON format, any syntax error in that parameter file will trigger this message.

You can fix this by pasting your JSON into an online JSON syntax checker, or by viewing the JSON in any modern editor that supports syntax highlighting, for example VS Code. This will show you any missing commas, colons or curly brackets.

In my case I had an extra comma, but any JSON syntax error will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error because my json for the template configuration was invalid

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?